# how to put object to the aws s3 bucket using a spring boot-web application

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-s3

how to read the request body in spring boot application

**aws --debug s3api --endpoint-url http://localhost:5555 put-object --bucket example_bucket --key test --body C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\test.txt**

how to read --body value in my spring boot application so that it becomes the request body for my endpoint

Comment: Have you ever tried spring cloud libraries?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-aws-s3

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_resource_handling

You can add spring-cloud-aws or typically you can add spring cloud bom.
Also you can configure like the link above

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [minio-java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java). It is SDK for Amazon S3 compatible cloud storage.

Comment: I dont want to use aws sdk i just want to read the post request body in a spring boot application